Finding distance between two first vertexes of line in QGIS
I need to know if there is an expression, or tool to perform the following operations: extract the distance (2D or 3D), between the first two vertexes of a line or polygon.

This Expression calculates the distance between the first and second vertex in the units of the layers coordinate reference system:
distance(point_n($geometry, 1), point_n($geometry, 2))


does it return 3D distance in case of z geometry or is it always 2D ?

There is no info on this in the docs. I guess you could make a line from the 2 vertices and then use length3D.
